# Drupal 7 OpenID module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7

I would like to as how can we have the login similar to the stackoverflow openid using drupal 7? In stackoverflow, we have various login options like facebook, google, etc, the image is show to choose various accounts. But I tried for drupal 7, only the 'Log in using OpenID' is shown beneath the login options. How do I show the multiple account options besides 'Log in using OpenID'.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Janrain/RPX Module](http://drupal.org/project/rpx).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Interesting service seems to be Janrain, it's paid but if works as it says then it's a very good price for commercial sites. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create some HTML that shows the OpenID providers that you want to mention explicitly.
2. Create some JavaScript that fills in the text input field when clicking on the OpenID provider in the HTML.
3. Wrap it into a Drupal module.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this process? Or maybe link to a guide/tutorial? I want to do this, but I don't want to muck around with hacking drupal core..

Comment: If you want to dig into Drupal module development, go to the [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules). If you don't, use the [OpenID Selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector) module (which uses the same JavaScript Library that StackExchange uses) or the [Janrain Engage](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) module that Ethan mentioned (which uses the Janrain Engage service to proxy authentication requests).